# How do I stop a sprite from moving once it is killed

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision, pygame-surface

I am trying to make a game in pygame for a com sci project. The layout is extremely similar to [Galaga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaga) or any other top down shooter type arcade game. The problem I have right now is that once a sprite is killed, the sprite still moves. I want to stop the sprites from moving so that I can time the bullet drops.

In other words, I am basing the enemy attacks off their x positions, and once a sprite is dead they keep moving, so the enemy attacks anyway. **Is there any way to stop a sprite from moving once it is dead or detect that is dead so that I can stop it myself? Thanks!**

Sorry if I missed any necessary code, I didn't want to put too much filler.

```
     #Enemy class #1
        class Kevin(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

            # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
            # and its x and y position
            def __init__(self, width, height):
                # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #Python 2.7 version

                self.image = (pygame.image.load(r"IMAGE"))

                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            def change(self,speedx,speedy):
                self.rect.x += speedx
                self.rect.y += speedy

    #Enemy attack
        class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

            # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
            # and its x and y position
            def __init__(self, width, height):
                # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #Python 2.7 version       
                 self.image = (pygame.image.load(r"IMAGE"))

                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            def change(self,speedx,speedy):
                self.rect.x += speedx
                self.rect.y += speedy

     ...
     def minions(enemyx,enemyy,changex,a,b):
            global list1
            for i in range(a,b):
                enemyx += changex
                list1.append(i)
                list1[i] = Kevin(100,100)
                list1[i].rect.x = enemyx
                list1[i].rect.y = enemyy
                list2.append(i)
                list2[i] = Kevin(100,100)
                list2[i].rect.x = enemyx
                list2[i].rect.y = enemyy
                enemy_list.add(list1[i])
                all_sprite_list.add(list1[i])
      ...
       def lazerdrop(x,y,a,b):
            for i in range(a,b):
                list3.append(i)
                list3[i] = Bullet(100,100)
                list3[i].rect.x = x
                list3[i].rect.y = y
                lazer_list.add(list3[i])
                all_sprite_list.add(list3[i])
        for d in range(7):
            lazerdrop(-400,105,0,d)
        minions(-500,100,80,0,5)
     ...
             all_sprite_list.update()

            screen.fill(BLACK)



            all_sprite_list.draw(screen)
     ...




     #If enemy is hit by lazer
            blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemy_list,block_list,True,True)
            if len(blocks_hit_list) == 1:                  
                score += 200
...
  #If the enemy reaches a certan x point, drop a lazer 
        if list1[10].rect.x > 168 and list1[10].rect.x < 175:
            list3[1].rect.x = list1[10].rect.x
            list3[1].rect.y = list1[10].rect.y
            list3[2].rect.x = list1[11].rect.x
            list3[2].rect.y = list1[11].rect.y
```

Comment: if you keep Sprite on list or in Group and later you draw all elements from list/group then remove Sprite from list/group. Group should have even option which removes killed object automatically.

Comment: or use some variable - ie. `self.kiled` - to control if it should move or not.

Comment: use it [groupcollide( ..., dokill1=True, dokill2=False)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) to remove killed enemies from group.

Comment: do you use `enemy_list` to draw enemies ? If you have enemies on other list which you use to draw them then you may have to remove them from other list. You should have killed enemies in `blocks_hit_list` and you could use `Sprite.kill` to remove them from all lists.

Comment: Not sure if this is how I reply to comments so sorry if this dosen't work but I am using enemy list to differentiate sprites, I use all_sprite_list to draw all sprites on screen. Should I separately add a function in my enemy class for blitting the enemy sprites?

Comment: @furas sorry still new to this, i am still having problems detecting the sprite death

Comment: @m What do you mean by *"detecting the sprite death"*? See [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). The 2 boolean parameters at the end cause that the sprites are killed. You kill the sprites: `pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemy_list,block_list,True,True)`. Your sprites are gone, they can't move on.

Comment: how do you draw them? Do you use `enemy_list.draw()` or you have another group to draw them? It would remove them from `enemy_list` but not from another group and you have to remove them manually. See what you get in `blocks_hit_list` - it should be list of killed enemies and you can use `for`-loop with this list to execute `.kill()` for every enemy and it should remove them from all groups.

Comment: @Rabbid76 the problem is that once the sprites are gone their x values continue to move for some reason, I don't know how to stop that.

Comment: @furas I now use enemy_list.draw() to draw my enemy sprites but their x values continue to move and even though they stop being blitted once they die, I can't detect their death in any way. I tried using self.kill() but it didn't work.

Comment: you should get all killed enemies in list `blocks_hit_list` so you should use it to kill them - not `self.kill()` but `for item  in blocks_hit_list: item.kill()` - or use this for-loop to set `item.speedx = 0` (if you have `self.speedx` in every Sprite). OR add some variable like `self.is_killed = False` at start, and later in loop set `item.is_killed  = True` and use `is_killed` in `update()` to move or not move it.

Answer (score 0):

*Because I needed the x and y values to fit a specific parameter I blit the objects off screen to see if they have been hit, I know there are better ways of doing this but this is fine for now*

Essentially, blocks_hit_list is a list of dead sprites that refreshes every time an enemy is killed. I can call up the "killed" function (blits the object off screen) for every "dead" sprite in the list. The sprite still exists in the idea that its x and y values can still be detected, my way of finally killing it is to change its x and y values to not fit my parameters.

```html
#If enemy is hit by lazer
        blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemy_list,block_list,True,True)
        if len(blocks_hit_list) == 1:                  
            score += 200
            list4 = sorted(blocks_hit_list)
            list4[0].killed(900,900)
            
...
 #If the enemy reaches a certan x point, drop a lazer 
        if list1[10].rect.x > 168 and list1[10].rect.x < 175:
            list3[1].rect.x = list1[10].rect.x
```